# Is Lion (gold master) part of the iOS Developers Program?

Tags: ios, macos, osx-lion

I know beta versions of Lion are available to iOS Dev Program members, but is the final release of Lion also available for download?

I am trying to avoid paying for Lion twice (once via the App Store and once via joining the Dev program).

Comment: If you're going to join the dev program anyway, why don't you just sign up and see if Lion is available?

Comment: beta versions of OS X are **not** available to iOS Dev Program members - though in 2009 Snow Leopard ß was made available to WWDC attendees who were not Mac OS Program members

Answer (score 1):

Pre-release versions of OS X are part of the Mac Dev Program, not the iOS Dev Program.

For what it's worth, when I logged in to the Mac App Store today, it showed it as already installed (I had downloaded the GM build a few weeks ago).  I deleted the previously downloaded GM and it let me download it again for free, so apparently being a member of the Mac Dev Program and having downloaded a beta version allows you the release version for free!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Do you pay individually for membership in each program?

Comment: Yes, the iOS and Mac dev programs are separate, both with a cost of $100.